# Plotting Chebyshev polynomials using PolarPlot and FilledCurve

Tags: plotting, polynomials

This question is related to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55217/66842).

What should I change in the following code to replace black color with blue color in the second image?

```
PolarPlot[Evaluate @ Table[n + ChebyshevT[n, t/Pi - 1], {n, 0, 40, 2}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
Graphics @ FilledCurve @ Cases[%, _Line, -1]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the styling directives before the graphics taken from the plot:

```
PolarPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[n + ChebyshevT[n, t/Pi - 1], {n, 0, 40, 2}],
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
Graphics[{Blue, FilledCurve@Cases[%, _Line, -1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the background color as well?

Comment: @PeđaTerzić Have you looked up the `Background` option to `Graphics`?  Just add it.

Answer (score 3):

```
plrplt = PolarPlot[Evaluate@Table[n + ChebyshevT[n, t/Pi - 1], {n, 0, 40, 2}], {t, 0, 2 π}];
```

To get different colors between layers you can sort the lines by the area of minimal bounding disk and replace `Line`s with `Polygon`s:

```
sorted = SortBy[-Area[BoundingRegion[#, "MinDisk"]] &] @ Cases[plrplt, Line[x_] :> x, All];

colors = { Yellow, Red, White, Blue};

Graphics[{First[colors = RotateLeft@colors], Polygon @ #} & /@ sorted]
```

[image]

An alternative way to get the same picture is to partition sorted lines and use `FilledCurve` for each pair:

```
Graphics[{First[colors=RotateLeft@colors], FilledCurve[Line/@#]}&/@ Partition[sorted, 2, 1]]
```

> same picture